# How to solve "Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDevelopmentDebug'" error in flutter android

Tags: android, flutter

I have a Flutter mobile app with Firebase. I am using real Android mobile device.  Whenever I run "flutter run", I get this error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script '/Users/aimnblbol/Developer/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle' line: 1159

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDevelopmentDebug'.
> Process 'command '/Users/aimnblbol/Developer/flutter/bin/flutter'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

I tried these things without any luck:

```
rm pubspec.lock
flutter clean
```

I noticed that the only way I can make a single build is if I delete android/app/build directory.

Here is how the pubspec.yaml file look:

```
version: 1.1.1+18
publish_to: none

environment:
  sdk: '>=2.18.6 <3.0.0'
  flutter: 3.3.10

dependencies:
  android_id: ^0.1.3+1
  badges: ^2.0.3
  cached_network_image: ^3.2.3
  carousel_slider: ^4.2.0
  cloud_firestore: ^4.2.0
  cloud_functions: ^4.0.6
  connectivity_plus: ^3.0.2
  device_info_plus: ^8.0.0
  dotted_border: ^2.0.0+3
  firebase_app_check: ^0.1.1+6
  firebase_auth: ^4.1.5
  firebase_core: ^2.3.0
  firebase_dynamic_links: ^5.0.8
  firebase_messaging: ^14.1.4
  firebase_remote_config: ^3.0.7
  firebase_storage: ^11.0.7
  firebase_ui_firestore: ^1.1.1
  flash: ^2.0.5
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_dotenv: ^5.0.2
  flutter_facebook_auth: ^4.4.1+1
  flutter_hooks: ^0.18.5+1
  flutter_image_compress: ^1.1.3
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.11.0
  flutter_local_notifications: ^12.0.4
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_slidable: ^2.0.0
  flutter_svg: ^1.1.6
  geocoding: ^2.0.5
  geolocator: ^9.0.2
  google_fonts: ^3.0.1
  google_sign_in: ^5.4.2
  hooks_riverpod: ^2.1.1
  http: ^0.13.5
  image_cropper: ^3.0.1
  image_picker: ^0.8.6
  intl: ^0.17.0
  linkable: ^3.0.1
  material_design_icons_flutter: ^6.0.7096
  open_mail_app: ^0.4.5
  package_info_plus: ^3.0.2
  path_provider: ^2.0.11
  pattern_formatter: ^2.0.0
  permission_handler: ^10.2.0
  photo_view: ^0.14.0
  purchases_flutter: ^4.5.0
  rate_my_app: ^1.1.3
  share_plus: ^6.3.0
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.15
  shimmer: ^2.0.0
  store_redirect: ^2.0.1
  timeago: ^3.3.0
  tuple: ^2.0.1
  url_launcher: ^6.1.7
  uuid: ^3.0.7
  webview_flutter: ^3.0.4

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  mocktail: ^0.3.0
  very_good_analysis: ^3.1.0

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  generate: true
  assets:
    - assets/env/
    - assets/email_icons/
    - assets/flags/
    - assets/images/
    - assets/json/
    - assets/social_icons/
```

Any idea how to resolve this error.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I debugged the problem slowly and discovered that the flutter_dotenv package was causing this problem.

In my code, I had assets/env/.develeopment.env file. In pubspec.yaml, I have assets/env/ under assets.  For some reason, the system did not like this directory to be under assets/env/.  When I moved it to env/ then the exception disappeared.  I am not clear why this is the case.  But this is how I resolved  the issue.